# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException

Tags: android, firebase, proguard

Code is working fine when in debug mode . It thorws the error only with minify enabled. I am stuck for more than 6 hours trying hit and trail.

> com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
>                                                                                         at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.need_a.b.b$3.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.firebase.client.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>                                                                                      Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of long from String value

Please find below the complete proguard content.

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.** { *; }


-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.**

-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-dontnote com.firebase.client.core.GaePlatform
-dontwarn org.apache.**


-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
@org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }
```

I request for help in this . Thanks in advance.